# Show that$\langle f_n\rangle$ is Uniformly Cauchy on $[1,\infty)$, where $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(\ln{x})^k}{k!xe^x}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

I want to show the sequence of functions $f_n : [1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly Cauchy.
$$ f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(\ln{x})^k}{k!xe^x} $$

My attempt:

I use Taylor expansion of $e^x \approx 1+ \cdots + \frac{1}{(k-1)!}x^{k-1}$ and $\ln{x}\approx x-1$ but it leads to
$$ \Vert f_m - f_n \Vert_{\sup} \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{1}{k}.$$
Since RHS does not goes to $0$, it fails.
Is there any other good way?

Comment: $\sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{1}{k}$ does not tend to $0$ so your proof doesn't work.

Comment: @geetha290krm
I know. That's why I ask a question here. I'll have to correct that part because other people might get confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x \ge 1$ and $k \ge 2$ is
$$
 x = e^{\ln x} \ge \frac{(\ln x)^{k-2}}{(k-2)!}
$$
and therefore
$$
\frac{(\ln{x})^k}{k!xe^x} \le \frac{(\ln x)^2}{(k-1)k e^x} \, .
$$
Using $\ln x \le x$ and $e^x > x^2/2$ it follows that
$$
\frac{(\ln{x})^k}{k!xe^x} \le \frac{2}{(k-1)k}
$$
Since $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{2}{(k-1)k}$ is convergent it follows that $(f_n)$ is uniformly Cauchy.

Concretely: For $2 < n < m$ is
$$
\Vert f_m - f_n \Vert_{\sup} \le \sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{2}{(k-1)k}
= 2 \sum_{k=n+1}^m \left( \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k} \right)
= 2 \left ( \frac 1n- \frac 1m\right) < \frac 2n \, .
$$